# What is the name used in literature and libraries for the abstraction of "zero profunctors"

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, purescript, category-theory, profunctor

In real world application I noticed a pattern that could be generalized to something like:

purescript:

```
class Profunctor p <= Zero p where
  pzero :: forall a b. p a b -- such that `forall f g. dimap f g pzero == pzero`
```

It seems basic enough to have its own name in literature and libraries out there.
So what is its name? (`Zero` and `pzero` are made up by me.)

UPDATE

I realized I made wrong generalization. My real world data type could provide infinitely many `pzero` implementations while what I really meant was a unique `pzero` that was identity for `psum :: forall a b . p a b -> p a b -> p a b`. So what I was looking a name for was rather:

purescript:

```
class Profunctor p <= Sum p where
  psum :: forall a b . p a b -> p a b -> p a b -- such that `psum a (psum b c) == psum (psum a b) c

class (Profunctor p, Sum p) <= Zero p where
  pzero :: forall a b. p a b -- such that `psum pzero p == p == psum p pzero`
```

(possibly without `Profunctor p` constrain).

This looks like a dual of Product Profunctor so I would call it Sum Profunctor, unless the literature and libraries discovered it already under a different name.

Comment: `pzero` appears to be a fixed point for `dimap f g`. Is it supposed to be the same value for *all* `f` and `g`?

Comment: yes, for all f and g (I'm updating code in the post)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's fixed point for `dimap f g` as the left-hand `pzero` is of different type than right-hand `pzero`.

Comment: At least in Haskell, you'll have to be specific about your definition of `==`, because for arbitrary `f :: a -> b` and `g :: c -> d`, `dimap f g pzero` cannot be compared with `pzero` itself.

Comment: I mean `==` in terms of equational reasoning.

Comment: Zero seems like a good name, like zero morphism. Note that this is equivalent to having `p () Void`.

Answer (score 4):

Your definition looks like what you want is a monoid in the Cartesian monoidal category of profunctors. This is quite similar (though not dual) to Product profunctors which are [monoids wrt a different monoidal structure: the Day convolution.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.00852.pdf)

As for naming, this is the analog of MonadPlus so I would probably go with ProfunctorPlus to match that

Answer (score -3):

In literature and libraries, the abstraction of "zero profunctors" is commonly referred to as "identity profunctors." These are profunctors that are the identity on objects, meaning they map every object to itself and every arrow to itself.

Comment: I think you may be confusing zero and one. An identity maps everything to itself. The OP is asking for a zero element, which maps everything to a particular value, in the same way that multiplying by zero will always produce zero, regardless of the other multiplicand.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).